# Why does lsblk report partition as "null" from within a docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, block-device

The following lsblk command returns "null" for several fields when called from within my archlinux container. On my natively running system the lsblk command returns values for all fields as expected.

```
lsblk --json -b -o+partn,partuuid,parttype,uuid /dev/sdd
```

Here's my docker run command.

```
docker run \
    --env PS1="mycontanier(\#)[\d \T:\w]\\$ " \
    --interactive \
    --privileged \
    --device=/dev/sdd \
    --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN \
    --rm \
    --tty \
    "mycontainer:latest"
```

And here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.io/archlinux:latest

ENV NAME=mycontainer VERSION=rolling

RUN pacman -Sy --noconfirm \
    git \
    dosfstools \
    arch-install-scripts \
    reflector \
    python-archinstall \
    rsync \
    pkgconf


RUN pacman -Scc --noconfirm

# Configure reflector
RUN reflector \
    --latest 5 \
    --protocol http,https \
    --save "/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist" \
    --sort rate

CMD /usr/bin/bash
```

What should I modify about my container to make these lsblk report the correct values for my drive?

Comment: The comment from this question doesn't bode well for me

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67887748/emulate-a-block-device-in-a-docker-container

"Docker doesn't simulate hardware devices in any form; a virtual-machine setup might work better for you."

Comment: As documented in man, lsblk relies on /sys. try using strace before lsblk to see what it can fail to find in /sys.

Answer (score 0):

I quote the accepted answer from the post
[How to access block device inside a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69040837/how-to-access-block-device-inside-a-docker-container).

> For hardware device, you will need to give capabilities to container
> to operation the device, there are 2 options here:
>
> **Option 1: Use privileged**
>
> See [Full container capabilities
> (--privileged)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#full-container-capabilities---privileged):
>
> ```
> # docker container run --rm --privileged --name c1 -it --mount type=bind,source=/dev/sdb,target=/data centos
> [root@7ab2eaef67cd /]# ls -al /data
> brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Sep  3 08:13 /data
> [root@7ab2eaef67cd /]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/data bs=1 count=1
> 1+0 records in
> 1+0 records out
> 1 byte copied, 0.00710505 s, 0.1 kB/s
> [root@7ab2eaef67cd /]# exit
> ```
>
> **Option 2: Use --device**
>
> See [Add host device to container
> (--device)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-host-device-to-container---device):
>
> ```
> # docker container run --rm --name c1 -it --device=/dev/sdb:/data centos
> [root@3a05b15b3b96 /]# ls -al /data
> brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Sep  3 08:15 /data [root@3a05b15b3b96 /]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/data bs=1 count=1
> 1+0 records in
> 1+0 records out
> 1 byte copied, 0.00326708 s, 0.3 kB/s
> [root@3a05b15b3b96 /]# exit
> ```

Comment: Sorry, but neither one of those work. I've tried the --device flag and the bind mount technique doesn't work either. Still null from lsblk

Comment: I should note that I don't have a problem writing files to the device if it's mounted within the container. That's not the issue. The issue is that lsblk reports null for fields like partn when called within the container, but returns accurate information when called from the host

Comment: I'm at a loss to understand why the `--device` flag didn't make the device totally visible. My only explanation is a deficiency in the docker runtime. It would perhaps be useful to post the problem on the docker forums.